# CSS styling of native (inbuilt) wordpress thumbnails

Tags: css, gallery

I really hope someone will be able to help me with this as it should be really simple but I am struggling!

I am working on the 'native' or inbuilt wordpress thumbnail gallery (not a plugin). I want to make it responsive. At the moment, on smaller screens, the thumbnails just get smaller...
I am trying to have them re-arrange themselves so that for example on screens above 1000px wide there are 5 thumbnails in a row, then between 700and 1000 px it goes down to 3 etc..

So my questions are:

-where in the wordpress folder is/are the css file(s) that affects these thumbnails? (they are the native, or inbuilt thumbnails that come with wordpress, regardless of my theme)

-How would you go about doing this? I want to set up media queries in the CSS file mentioned above, once I find which one it is... does that sound right?

I am thinking of keeping the original styling and adding stuff to it, including the media queries.  Is that possible or do I need to unhook the css and thenrewrite it from scratch?
If that is the case, how do I unhook?  In which file does this happen?

Any help at this stage would be most gratefully received... any help, pointers, snippets etc would be a huge help.

Thanks in advance,
Maya

Comment: As it is written by now it sound like a CSS question about how to write responsive pages, which is off-topic for the site. If the question is about more then that please edit it and clarify it.

Answer (score 2):

The [gallery_shortcode](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/gallery_shortcode) with its default styles can be found in [wp-includes/media.php](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.9.2/src/wp-includes/media.php#L906) line 906 to 1089. There is also an article in the codex that might be useful: [Gallery Shortcode](http://codex.wordpress.org/Gallery_Shortcode). There is also a couple of filters available as you can see from the source code that you can use

The gallery shortcode uses the default thumbnail size, which is 150 x 150 px. This can be changed like below to use the medium size thumbnail

```
[gallery size="medium"]
```

As for the responsiveness, you are going to have to figure out something there. I don't have any time to code now or test, but it might become necessary to create your own shortcode, because, AFAIK, the type of responsiveness does not exists in the current shortcode. I would think that you will need to strip the complete section of code from the source code which handles adding columns to the gallery

I hope this helps you in some constructive way in solving your issue